# Optimization of a command involving a sum and an exponential

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization, time

I am coding in python, using numpy. I want to optimize a formula that looks like that, I use a picture for the sake of readibility. [image]

In that example, the times t are from different lists, indicated by the superscript. The corresponding vector here is T_t, which is a list of list. 
Here is my original code:

```
def first_version(m, n, k, T_t, BETA):
    if k == 1:
        return 0
    ans = 0
    for i in range(len(T_t[n])):
        if T_t[n][i] < T_t[m][k - 1]:
            ans += (T_t[m][k - 1] - T_t[n][i]) * np.exp(-BETA[m, n] * (T_t[m][k - 1] - T_t[n][i]))
        else:
            break
    return ans
```

The break at the end allows me to spare some time. I had that brilliant idea of using the numpy library to improve the performances:

```
def second_version(m, n, k, T_t, BETA):
    if k == 1:
        return 0
    the_times = np.maximum( T_t[m][k - 1] - np.array(T_t[n]) , 0  )
    ans = sum(the_times * np.exp( -BETA[m, n] * the_times  ))
    return ans
```

For the sake of comparison, the second algorithm runs 100x faster. Is it possible to do better ? In particular, I regret the fact that numpy computes the maximum over the whole vector when probably half of it will be 0 at the end.

Do you have any idea how to improve those bits of code ?

---

I forgot a sum in the code nr 2. That slows down the code and make it only 20 times faster.

Comment: Please provide some example data for us to test with. Doesn't need to be real data; just something with roughly the same shape and statistical properties as the real data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 2 main suggestions:

- Using `np.sum()` instead of `sum()` about triples the speed of `second_version`
- Using `numba.jit` increases the speed again about 8x. (Actually you can jit-compile either version and end up with about the same speed)

Full code example:

```
import numpy as np
import numba
import timeit


def first_version(m, n, k, T_t, BETA):
    if k == 1:
        return 0
    ans = 0
    for i in range(len(T_t[n])):
        if T_t[n][i] < T_t[m][k - 1]:
            ans += (T_t[m][k - 1] - T_t[n][i]) * np.exp(-BETA[m, n] * (T_t[m][k - 1] - T_t[n][i]))
        else:
            break
    return ans


def second_version(m, n, k, T_t, BETA):
    if k == 1:
        return 0
    the_times = np.maximum( T_t[m][k - 1] - np.array(T_t[n]) , 0  )
    ans = np.sum(the_times * np.exp( -BETA[m, n] * the_times  ))
    return ans


def jit_version(m, n, k, T_t, BETA):
    # wrapper makes it to that numba doesn't have to deal with 
    # the list-of-arrays data type
    return jit_version_core(k, T_t[m], T_t[n], BETA[m, n])


@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def jit_version_core(k, t1, t2, b):
    if k == 1:
        return 0
    ans = 0
    for i in range(len(t2)):
        if t2[i] < t1[k - 1]:
            ans += (t1[k - 1] - t2[i]) * np.exp(-b * (t1[k - 1] - t2[i]))
        else:
            break
    return ans


N = 10000
t1 = np.cumsum(np.random.random(size=N))
t2 = np.cumsum(np.random.random(size=N))
beta = np.random.random(size=(2, 2))

for fn in ['first_version', 'second_version', 'jit_version']:
    print("------", fn)
    v = globals()[fn](0, 1, len(t1), [t1, t2], beta)
    t = timeit.timeit('%s(0, 1, len(t1), [t1, t2], beta)' % fn, number=100, globals=globals())
    print("output:", v, "time:", t)
```

And the output:

```
------ first_version
output: 3.302938986817431 time: 2.900316455983557
------ second_version
output: 3.3029389868174306 time: 0.12064526398899034
------ jit_version
output: 3.302938986817431 time: 0.013476221996825188
```

Comment: what is Jit? Thanks for the np.sum version.

Comment: numba is a just-in-time (JIT) compiler for python. When you run a function decorated with `@numba.jit`, it gets compiled down to a much simpler / faster piece of code, as long as you stay within a limited subset of python. Highly recommended tool, and it has a lot of support within the scientific python community.